# Find first duplicate element with lowest second occurrence index

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to solve a problem on CodeFights called `firstDuplicate`, that states -

> Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to
>   a.length, find the first duplicate number for which the second
>   occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more
>   than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second
>   occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other
>   number does. If there are no such elements, return -1.
>
> Example
>
> For a = [2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2], the output should be firstDuplicate(a) =
>   3.
>
> There are 2 duplicates: numbers 2 and 3. The second occurrence of 3
>   has a smaller index than than second occurrence of 2 does, so the
>   answer is 3.
>
> For a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1], the output should be firstDuplicate(a) = -1.

My solution -

```
public class FirstDuplicate {
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    private static void findSecondIndexFrom(int[] num, int n, int i) {
    // given an array, a starting index and a number, find second occurrence of that number beginning from next index
        for(int x = i; x < num.length; x++) {
            if(num[x] == n) {
              // second occurrence found - place in map and terminate
                counts.put(n, x);
                return;
            }
        }


    }

    private static int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
        // for each element in loop, if it's not already in hashmap
        // find it's second occurrence in array and place number and index in map

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(!counts.containsKey(a[i])) {
                findSecondIndexFrom(a, a[i], i+1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(counts);
        // if map is empty - no duplicate elements, return -1
        if(counts.size() == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        // else - get array of values from map, sort it, find lowest value and return corresponding key

        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(counts.values());
        Collections.sort(values);
        int lowest = values.get(0);
        //System.out.println(lowest);
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entries: counts.entrySet()) {
            if(entries.getValue() == lowest) {
                return entries.getKey();
            }
        }
     return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // int[] a = new int[]{2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2};
         //int[] a = new int[]{2, 4, 3, 5, 1};
         //int[] a = new int[]{8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 7, 9, 5, 8};
        //int[] a = new int[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 1};

        int[] a = new int[]{10, 6, 8, 4, 9, 1, 7, 2, 5, 3};
        System.out.println(firstDuplicate(a));
    }


}
```

This solution passes only for about 4 of the 11 test cases on CodeFights. However, I manually executed each one of the test cases in my IDE, and each one produces the right result.

I can't figure out why this won't work in CodeFights. Does it have something to do with the use of the static `HashMap`?

Comment: Might be, try adding a `counts.clear()` to the beginning of `firstDuplicate()`...

Comment: Any idea of how to do this problem without using extra space (maps here)

Comment: why do we need a map?, it is enough to track the minimum index

Comment: @IshaAgarwal I tried out another way which does not use any additional storage(maps, or sets). This approach uses two `int` variables to check/track the current lowest second index, and element with lowest second index values and sets these variables in subsequent iterations only if the conditions are satisfied. The code is on this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Manish-Giri/0fe75f36364b294eb68d5a3eca3abe27).

While all the sample tests are passing, there seem to be 2 failing custom tests, so I need to refine this further. But pretty sure this is the way to go for `O(1)` space comp.

Answer (score 3):

Edited: Since adding and checking if element is present in Set can be done in one step, code can be simplified to:

```
public static int findDuplicateWithLowestIndex(int... a){
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
   for(int num : a){
     if(!set.add(num)){
        return num;
       }
    }
return -1; 
}
```

You're completly right Patrick.

Comment: more efficient: `if (!set.add(num)) return num;`

Comment: @Snusifer my comment was improving upon a previous version of the answer. click the "Edited" link to see the post history to see what was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution: here duplicateIndex  should be very large number.

```
    package sample;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Duplicate {

public static Integer secondIndex(Integer[] arr) {
    List<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    int duplicateIndex = 999;
    int ele = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrlist.size(); i++) {
        int secondIndex = getSecondIndex(arrlist, arrlist.get(i));

        if (secondIndex >= 0 && duplicateIndex > secondIndex) {
            duplicateIndex = secondIndex;
            ele = arrlist.get(i);
        }
    }

    return duplicateIndex == 999 ? -1 : ele;
}

public static int getSecondIndex(List<Integer> arr, int ele) {
    List<Integer> var0 = new ArrayList<>(arr);
    var0.set(var0.indexOf(ele), -1);
    return var0.indexOf(ele);
}

public static void main(String[] str) {
    // Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2 };
    // Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 2, 4, 3, 5, 1 };
    // Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 7, 9, 5, 8 };
    // Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 1};
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 10, 6, 8, 4, 9, 1, 7, 2, 5, 3 };
    System.out.println(secondIndex(arr));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Javascript**

```js
function solution(a) {    
    const duplicates = [];
    for (const i of a) {
        if (duplicates.includes(i))
            return i;
        else
            duplicates.push(i);
    }
    
    return -1;
}

console.log(solution([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2])); // 3
console.log(solution([2, 2])); // 2
console.log(solution([2, 4, 3, 5, 1])); // -1
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, and cleanly written. Can you come up with a similar solution written in Java?