# Firstduplicate in array using java

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to find the duplicate number with lower indices.

For example if the array is **{1,4,3,5,3,2,1}** 
then the answer should be **3**,  because it is in smaller indices then the next repeated integer 1.

If no repeated number is found then needs to return -1. 
I Need to write an program which impalement it in o(n) time complexity.

I am able to solve it for the O(n^2) probability but dont know how to do it for O(n). Also i am not understanding how to implement if no repeated digits are found.
Kindly help me. I am stuck here.

Thank you in advance.

My code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class firstDuplicate
{
    //defining array
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
     int[] a1 = new int[] {2,3,3,1,5,2};

    //int[] a1 = new int[] {2,3,4,1,5,8};

    for(int i=0;i<a1.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(a1[i]);
    }
    int counter =0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();


    for(int i =0; i<a1.length; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<a1.length; j++) 
        {
            if(a1[i]==a1[j])
            {
                counter =counter+1;
                System.out.println(j);
                list1.add(j);

            }
            else {
                int k =-1;
                System.out.println(k);
            }
        }


    }

    System.out.println("Printing ur numbers of repetation");
    System.out.printf("%d",counter);
    System.out.println("If printed ur answer is following");
    int k = Collections.min(list1);
    System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and improve the formatting.

Comment: okay great. That's what you are trying to do.  What's the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find first duplicate element with lowest second occurrence index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667037/find-first-duplicate-element-with-lowest-second-occurrence-index)

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed like this:

- Create an empty Set, then for each element in the input Array,
- Check if the element is already in the Set

  - If yes then stop the algorithm here and return the current element as the result
  - If no then add the current element to the set and continue with the next element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Thanks to Saka1029 and Patrick Parker.

Idea stays the same - we're using Set in order to find the first duplicate element, but instead of splitting adding and checking if element already is present in Set into two separate operations (we generally want to find the first duplicate with as little steps as possible) - in 'if' (is present in Set) and 'else' (add to Set) structure, we can simplify it into single 'if' statement as Saka1029 pointed out.

```
public static int findDuplicateWithLowestIndext(int... a){

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for(int num : a){

// since add() returns a true if elemenet was added and false if it wasn't -
// due to being duplicate -  we can add elements and look for duplicate
// at the same time

     if(!set.add(num)){
        return num;
        }
     }
   return -1; 
 }
```

As for bigO goes, to make things simple I'll put it this way: since we are traversing a single time through whole array and in method body we are using a single add() method from Set, which by itself is O(1) - this is how we end up with O(n) - although that's simplified way of putting it.

Comment: The if-statement can be `if (!set.add(num)) return num;`.

Comment: Sure, add() returns a boolean.

Comment: @M.Bugiel for this answer to be complete, you should describe the big-O costs for set insertion. and set membership check. unless you get rid of the set membership check (you should do that), as suggested by saka1029

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first indices of all duplicate values using a stream/lookup combination:

```
List<Integer> l = List.of(1,4,3,5,3,2,1);

l.stream()
  //Compute a map of elements -> occurrence count:
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
 .entrySet()
 .stream()
  //Limit stream to values occurring more than once
 .filter(it -> it.getValue() > 1)
  //Find the first index of each key
 .map(entry -> l.indexOf(entry.getKey()))
 .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The above returns this list:

```
[0, 2]
```

Comment: should find the second index

Comment: based on this algortihm, we would have chosen value 1 as the first duplicate. but OP stated that value 3 is the first duplicate. because it is not the first index of the value that matters, but the second index that matters.

Answer (score 0):

A O(n) solution would be the following :

1. Create an array with size 10.
2. Each time you encounter a number, you check if the index corresponding is equals to 1.
3. If it is the case, you have your duplicate.
4. If no, you increment it.

---

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/VOuIvN)**

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println(getLowestDuplicate(1,4,3,5,3,2,1)); // 3
    System.out.println(getLowestDuplicate(2,3,3,1,5,2)); // 3
    System.out.println(getLowestDuplicate(1,4,5,3,2)); // -1
}

public static int getLowestDuplicate(int... numbers) {
    int[] counters = new int[10];
    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (counters[i] == 1) return i;
        counters[i] = counters[i] + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```